# to be in a special unit on one's own

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "to be in a special unit on one's own" mean? Does it mean to be in a special condition? ( the text I am reading is about children suffering from disabilities)

Context:

The film makes use of public information voiceovers from old National Health Service documentary material, which give what we would now regard as highly patronising information about mental disorder (‘they’re in a special unit on their own with – deformities’, ‘the child’s parents must be encouraged not to aim too high’)

Art and Science (Sian Ede)

Comment: It probably means a dedicated *hospital unit*: an area, wing, or ward set aside for the treatment of patients with some specific disease or disorder. If you copy in the larger context, and link to the source, we could tell you more.

Comment: @Dan Bron  the context is added :)

Comment: What's the obsession with this Ede character all about? Anyway, with the additional context: my initial guess was correct. There is a specific ward for the mentally ill children, and it has been named (as Ede says, in a defamatory way we would not use today) "Deformities".

Comment: @Dan Bron  thank you so much for your attention. I am reading this book and try to refer to natives and professionals whenever I feel confused about any unfamiliar phrase or sentence. Good news that i am getting close to the end of the book!